# Tableau: Hiding values in a chart with two dual axis

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, graph-visualization

I have a chart with dual x-axis and dual y-axis. 
My table currently looks like this:
[image]
Since there is 2 dual axis in my chart it is showing

- Blue x Depth
- Blue x Shapes
- Orange x Depth
- Orange x Shapes

I want to hide the Orange x Shapes portion of my chart. Is there a way to do this? Possibly filter it out from the view? I tried to right click the legend to hide or exclude "Square, Orange" and "Triangle, Orange" but the option isn't available.

Edit: Here is a workbook with dummy data [dummy workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XOPTqC8tWPOCrJj3agrCns_Q5Wr7wqs-)

Thank you!

Comment: A little bit of sample data would help.

Comment: Just a warning. Usually having 4 axis combined into one chart leads to more complexity than its worth, and there turns out to be a simpler way to get the same desired, or similar, effect. But I'd be curious to see some sample data to see if you've found a good use case for a quad axis chart.

Comment: Sample data is useful, but to have any idea of what you're trying to accomplish, will need a tableau workbook also in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I added a workbook with the dummy data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question in Tableau Community and a solution with screenshots has been posted:
[Solution](https://community.tableau.com/thread/282112)

The basic steps to solve this is to

1. In the Data Source tab, Union the data with itself which creates a column called [Table Name].
2. Create Two Calculated columns:
3. Orange 2 -> if [Table Name] = "Dummy Data" then [Orange]
4. Shape 2 -> if [Table Name] = "Dummy Data1" then [Shapes]
5. In the sheet/chart, replace Orange with Orange 2 and Shape with Shape 2
6. In the Depth mark, add Table Name to Details